# How to improve puppeteer performance using launch args (using chromium in headless mode)?

Tags: node.js, performance, puppeteer, puppeteer-cluster

Hi I am using puppeteer for crawling webpages(~1 Million records). For managing long crawls I am using puppeteer-cluster node module.

1. What are the flags that are already enabled when launching chromium using puppeteer? [list of args](https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/)
2. What are some args that will enable me to increase performance of puppeteer?

Currently I am using the following args to launch chromium:

```
args: [
  '--disable-setuid-sandbox',
  '--disable-dev-shm-usage',
  '--disable-accelerated-2d-canvas',
  '--no-first-run',
  '--disable-gpu'
]
```